# How to check if message failed in django-channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am using [channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/) in my project which made django to use websockets very easy to setup and use.

In my application every user that logs in opens a Group to which we can send information if there is any activity.

```
def ws_connect(message):
    Group("%s" % message.user.id).add(message.reply_channel)
```

so whenever I want to send a message to that user, I use

```
Group('%s' % user.id).send(
    {
        'text': json.dumps({
            'message': 'Some message'
        })
    }

)
```

But this fails silently if there is any error.
So question is there way to check if it failed or if there is any way we can check if the Group exists (live or listening ), even before I send data in order to handle it better.

Comment: `channel_layer.group_channels('<your group name>')` this will return the list  of client connected to that group. I think it will throw error when no group present.